# How to save and restore multiple context's in cocoa/quartz?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

Right now I do this:

```
CGContextRef context = NULL;
context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

[see if I need to restore]
[if so]
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

[do transformations and draw some stuff]

[save the current state]
CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

I want to have various states so I can go back to them. The way I am doing it now, it seems that I can only store one. Do I need multiple contexts? I'm guessing so, but I am not sure what the best way would be. I just got into cocoa, anyway, I thought I'd ask! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CGContextSaveGState`/`CGContextRestoreGState`, you can save multiple graphics states. The documentation for `CGContextSaveGState` says "Each graphics context maintains a stack of graphics states.".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want to implemented an undo manager rather than save different states. In this app [SimpleDrawing](https://bitbucket.org/nwoolls/simpledrawing/wiki/Home), there is a good example of using quartz with a undo manager and the context.

Comment: Thank you! That is a very useful answer and link. I can use this to further study what I have and want.